Создаю календарь
Ребят я бы хотел создать календарь и я хочу что бы сегодняшний день подсвечивался в чем проблема когда я сравниваю элементы с HTML и JS то они не совпадают из за пустых пространств поэтому через for loop у меня не получается вот весь код. (если что другое можно изменить и сократить можете сказать)


const now = new Date();
const currentDate = now.getDate();
const month = document.getElementById("month");
const days = month.querySelectorAll("div div");

for (let day of days) {
  if (day.textContent.trim() === currentDate.toString()) {
    day.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"
  }
};

function updateClock() {

  const now = new Date();
  let hours = now.getHours();
  const meridiem = hours >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
  hours = hours % 12 || 12;
  hours = hours.toString().padStart(2, 0);
  const minutes = now.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, 0);
  const seconds = now.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, 0);
  const timeString = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds} ${meridiem}`;
  document.getElementById("clock").textContent = timeString;
}

updateClock();
setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
body {
  background-image: url(backround4.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#calendar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  width: 350px;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 30%);
}

#year {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

#month {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

#slideButtons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: -20%;
  margin-left: 90px;
  margin-right: 90px;
  text-align: center;
}

#clock-container {
  margin-top: 7rem;
}

#clock {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.1);
}
<div id="calendar">
  <div id="year">2000/02/20</div>

  <div id="month">
    <div>1 2 3 4 5 6 7 <br></div>
    <div>8 9 10 11 12 13 14 <br></div>
    <div>15 16 17 18 19 20 21 <br></div>
    <div>22 23 24 25 26 27 28 <br></div>
    <div>29 30 31</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="slideButtons">
  <button class="prev" onclick="prevSlide()">&#10094</button>
  <button class="next" onclick="nextSlide()">&#10095</button>
</div>

<div id="clock-container">
  <div id="clock">00:00:00</div>
</div>



заранее спасибо!

Проблема совершенно не ясна. Если проблема в пустых пространствах - то удаляйте их... Так что не ясно с чем тут надо помогать

"за раннее" --- правильно будет "заранее"............ "и я хочу что бы" --- правильно будет "и я хочу, чтобы"......... "из за" --- правильно будет "из-за".  А ещё правильно расставлять знаки препинания, чтобы остальные могли спокойно прочесть и понять то, что написано

В чем именно вопрос? Ну для начала, что бы что то подсвечивать, лучше сделать даты каждую в своем контейнере и избавиться от строк div да еще и с переносом строки в конце

@SwaD это, кстати, не обязательно. Просто подсвечивание будет по-другому реализовано.

Нет возможности задать цвет отдельной части текста. Для этого необходимо обернуть эту часть в какой-нибудь элемент, например span
Сделать это можно сразу в разметке, либо в коде с проверкой
Например:


const now = new Date();
const currentDate = now.getDate();
const month = document.getElementById("month");
const days = month.querySelectorAll("div div");

for (let day of days) {
  day.innerHTML = day.textContent.replace(new RegExp(`\\b(${currentDate})\\b`), "<span class='current'>$&</span>")
};
body {
  background-image: url(backround4.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#calendar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  width: 350px;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 30%);
}

#year {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

#month {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.current {
  background-color: yellow;
}
<div id="calendar">
  <div id="year">2000/02/20</div>

  <div id="month">
    <div>1 2 3 4 5 6 7</div>
    <div>8 9 10 11 12 13 14</div>
    <div>15 16 17 18 19 20 21</div>
    <div>22 23 24 25 26 27 28</div>
    <div>29 30 31</div>
  </div>
</div>




Нет возможности задать цвет отдельной части текста
Вообще-то можно.

@AndreiFedorov каким образом?

@AndreiFedorov, в комментарии выше под вопросом, с вами согласится можно, т.к. "подсветить" что-либо можно разными способами. А вот изменить цвет части текстовой строки, я думаю, что ни завтра, и послезавтра, ни через несколько лет будет невозможно без оборачивания этой части в отдельный элемент.

@Grundy @Deonis background-clip: text

@AndreiFedorov, а как им подсвечивать отдельный кусок?

@AndreiFedorov, даже цитируя, вы пропускаете смысл слов. Думаю, что бессмысленно продолжать беседу.

@Grundy https://codepen.io/aliencash/pen/MGoGXz?editors=1100

@AndreiFedorov, проблема с градиентами в том, что у символов разный размер, и код не получится универсальным, под каждую строку нужно будет пересматривать настройки градиента

@Grundy, посмотрите на код автора - там моноширинный шрифт.

@AndreiFedorov, это не отменяет ручной настройки градиента

@Grundy Принципиально можно расцветить части текста без оборачивания их в отдельные тэги. Это все против чего я возражал.

@Grundy и др. спасибо за помощь, у меня подсветился сегодняшний день, но я конечно не понял как работает код, эту RegExp,  возможно это не трудно попробую понять.

@Человек, регулярное выражение ищет "слово" совпадающее с числом - если находит - заменяет
